# Jenkins: running docker commands on a docker slave

Tags: jenkins, docker, kubernetes

I'm using the [Kubernetes Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin) plugin to orchestrate jenkins slaves

I want to run all the jobs in Docker (build docker images and execute tests/builds in docker).

example jenkins job:

```
docker run -e NEXUS_USERNAME=${NEXUS_USERNAME} -e NEXUS_PASSWORD=${NEXUS_PASSWORD} common-dropwizard:latest mvn deploy
```

I am using the jenkinsci/jnlp-slave from here:  https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jnlp-slave/

Unfortunately, the slave image doesn't appear to support running docker.  My question is what is the best approach to accomplish this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install docker client and mount the docker socket so you can access the Docker host. Then you can interact with that Docker host

https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/tree/master/demo

Comment: DinD is probably not needed... mounting the socket via `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` works well.  Note that you will probably need to pass in the --privileged=true flag

Comment: I'm also trying to run docker commands but mapping the docker.sock and setting privileged true haven't worked.

I tried both configuring the pod in jenkins dashboard and using the pipeline podTemplate function.

A piece of my JenkinsFile (https://gist.github.com/otaviosoares/fc132dcb863e75161431ed00b95f06ba)

The image I'm using is based on jenkinsci/jnlp-slave with git and docker installed.

The error I get is "docker: not found" Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: then docker is not in the PATH or something like that

Comment: I figured out. I was not setting my container name to jnlp so it was creating another container inside the pod. Thanks